# Unable to take an inactive disk offline (unmount)

Tags: windows-7, unmount

My PC has two disks. One for Ubuntu and and the other for Windows 7/10.

In Windows 7, when I try to take a Ubuntu disk offline it won't let me. I was able to do this when I installed Windows 10.

Error message was "Disk attributes may not be changed on the current system disk or BIOS disk 0."

[image: Error in disk management MSC]

Clarification: Disk 0 = Ubuntu, Disk 1 = Windows 7.

Comment: As it's telling you there is important data on Disk 0 that is necessary to run the system.

Comment: @Seth, could you tell what would that important data be? I chose to install Windows 7 in disk 1 without touching the disk 0 in the process. And in Windows 10 I could unmount disk 0.

Comment: You probably did install Windows 10 differently. it's likely complaining about the [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition).